# Android String: Find Number and Create New String

Tags: android, arrays, string, spinner

I have a spinner that is populated with a list of strings such as "Item 1: 1.5 - 2.5" and I would like to somehow extract the number portions (1.5 - 2.5) from that string when it is selected from the spinner and then calculate the average of the two numbers.

My initial thought is to get the string when it is selected from the spinner, then use the copyValueOf method to extract just the numbers from the string, then add them to their own variables and determine the average. Unfortunately I have no idea how to set this up in code. How do I collect the numbers individually from the character array? All the numbers are 3 digits long (2.3) including the decimal, so maybe I can use getChars function on the array and get the first 3 characters into one variable and then the last 3 in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s="Item 1: 1.5 - 2.5"//s=spinner.getItemAt(i)
String newS[]=s.split(":");//newS[0]="Item 1" and newS[1]="1.5-2.5"
String newS2[]=newS[1].split("-");//

Double d1=Double.parseDouble(newS2[0]);
Double d2=Double.parseDouble(newS2[1]);
Double avg=(d1+d2)/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Item 1: 1.5 - 2.5";
String[] strs = str.split(":");

String numberStr = (strs[strs.length - 1]).trim();
String[] numbers = numberStr.split("-");

float sum = 0f;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + Float.valueOf(numbers[i]).floatValue();
}
//Here, get the average of the two numbers
float result = sum / (numbers.length);
```

This maybe the best sulotion but it works and I have tested it, hope this can help you.